# Sharing common helper scripts among projects in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, clojure, vscode-calva

I have a few utility functions, snippets and scratches that I want to be able to use in every project.
Currently I have the following setup for Clojure projects and Intellij IDEA/Cursive:

- I have a user profile defined in .lein, where I have source-paths pointing to
- when I sync and run REPL for project in IDEA/Cursive, I check that :user profile is selected (it is the default)
- Cursive shows both project files and common files (i.e. scratches folder) in project pane
- I can edit and eval in REPL real project files and my local helers/scratchpads seamlessly.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour in VSCode?

Notes:

- My clojure setup in Cursive is for illustration purposes only. I would like to find a way to get similar feature in other scripting languages (i.e. python, groovy). So ideally I don't want to use leiningen for that, but rather find a generic way to add common source folder to VS code Explorer pane.
- I know that with multi-root workspaces I can achieve what I want, but it must be done manually per project. It would be much better if my folder with common utils was added to every workspace automatically. Something like a default workspace template would solve this, but I couldn't find anything similar. Am I missing something?

[image]